# How can I make circuitz around a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circles

I wanted to reproduce this image [image]

But I am having trouble doing the resistor in the circle configuration, here is what I have done so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}    
\begin{center}\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.5]
        \draw[->] (-3.5,0) -- (-3.1,0);
        \node at (-3.5,0) [left] {$q_i$};
        \filldraw (-3,0) circle (1.2pt) node [above] {\large{$E_{cni}$}};
        \draw (-3,0) to[R,a=\Large{$\frac{1-\epsilon_{i}}{\epsilon_{i} A_{i}}$}, label distance=8pt,*-] (0,0);
        \filldraw (0,0) circle (1.2pt) node [below] {$J_{i}$};
        \draw[dotted, very thick] (0,0) circle (0.5);
    
         % Draw the resistors
        \draw (0,0) to [R=$(A_{i}F_{i1})^-1$] (230:2);
        \draw (0,0) to [R=$(A_{i}F_{i3})^-1$] (60:2);
        \draw (0,0) to [R=$(A_{i}F_{i2})^-1$] (130:2);
        \draw (0,0) to [R=$(A_{i}F_{iN-1})^-1$] (2.2,0);
        \draw (0,0) to [R=$(A_{i}F_{iN})^-1$] (310:2);
        \foreach \angle/\label in {230/$J_1$, 130/$J_2$, 60/$J_3$, 310/$J_N$}
        \node[circ,label={\label}] at (\angle:2) {};
        \filldraw (2.2,0) circle (1.2pt) node [right] {$J_{N-1}$};
\end{circuitikz}\end{center}\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to teX.SE! Which documentclass do you use? Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: See *5.1.3 Labels and annotation orientation.*, page 181, circuitiku package documentation-

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

I think you are

- mixing `circuitikz` element with hand-draw circles with no real reasons;
- failing to use relative coordinate when needed (the `++` thing)
- mixing polar and rectangular coordinates for the same elements
- calculating the wrong angles (I put the branches at units of 360/14 degrees consistently)
- not using sufficient space to have the label not overlap each other (if they don't fit, they don't fit)
- missing the `rotate` option to `label/align`

Try to start from this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (-0.1,0);
        \node [left] at (-0.5,0)  {$q_i$};
        \path (0,0) node[circ]{} node [above] {$E_{cni}$};
        \draw (0,0) to[R,l=\Large{$\frac{1-\epsilon_{i}}{\epsilon_{i} A_{i}}$}, label distance=8pt,*-] (3,0);
        \path (3,0) node[circ]{} node [above left=3mm] {$J_{i}$};
        \draw[dotted, very thick] (3,0) circle (0.5);
        \foreach \n in {1,2,...,3}{
            \draw (3,0) to[R,a=$(A_{\n}F_{i\n})^-1$, label distance=8pt,*-o, label/align=rotate] ++(\n*360/14: 5cm) node[above]{$J_\n$};
        }
        \draw (3,0) to[R,a=$(A_{N-1}F_{iN-1})^-1$, label distance=8pt,*-o] ++(0:5cm) node[right]{$J_{N-1}$};
        \draw (3,0) to[R,a=$(A_{N}F_{iN})^-1$, label distance=8pt,*-o] ++(-360/14:5cm) node[right]{$J_{N}$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Ah, you probably also want to use `...^{-1}`, with the group, but I did not change that.